# Not a Function Error in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

Whenever I try to add a "new" function to my controller and service, I receive this error:
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: companyServiceProvider <- companyService <- CompanyController

I play around with parts of the function a few times and then it miraculously starts working (the last time all I did was change the name of the function). There must be a way to prevent this from happening, but for the life of me, I can't figure it out.

Here is a snippet of my controller code:

```
myApp.controller("CompanyController",  function($scope, $timeout, companyService){

    $scope.SelectedCompanyId = '';
    $scope.form = {};
    $scope.lastState = true;
    pass = 0;
    $scope.addedStates = [];
    getCompanies();
    function getCompanies() {
        companyService.getCompanies()
            .success(function (data) {
                $scope.companies = data;
            })
         .error(function (error) {
             $scope.status = 'Unable to load customer data: ' + error.message;
         });
    };

    getModules();
    function getModules() {
        companyService.getModules()
        .success(function (data) {
            $scope.modules = data;
        })
        .error(function (error) {
            $scope.status = 'Unable to load Dashboard Modules: ' + error.message;
        });
    };
        getModuleColors();
    function getModuleColors() {
        companyService.getModuleColors()
        .success(function (data) {
            $scope.colors = data;
        })
        .error(function (error) {
            $scope.status = 'Unable to load Dashboard Modules: ' + error.message;
        });
    };
```

Here is a snippet of my servce:

```
angular.module('dashboardManagement')
.service('companyService'(), [
'$http', function ($http) {
    //this.selectedCompanyId = null;
    this.getCompanies = function () {
        return $http.get('/Home/GetAllCompanies');
    };
    this.getModules = function () {
        return $http.get('/Home/GetDashboardModules');
    };

    this.getModuleColors = function () {
        return $http.get('/Home/GetModuleColors');
    };
    this.getCurrentModules = function (companyId) {
        //this.selectedCompanyId = companyId;
        return $http.get('/Home/GetCurrentModules?companyId=' + companyId);

    };
```

The function that is throwing the error now is the "getModuleColors" function as it was the last one added.

The other functions work fine. Can someone PLEASE tell me what is going on here?

Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: why you use a () after the service name: 'companyService'() ??? it could to generate your reported error

Comment: actually, I added "()" after the service name because I saw that as a "solution" to another post where someone was experiencing the same problem.  It didn't help, nor did it throw any additional errors.

Comment: try to run on console: 'companyService'()

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but with or without the "()" I get the same error when pressing F12 in Chrome or using Debugger in IE

Comment: Yes, it isn't the point. Could you try to create a jsbin or jsfiddle with your code? We can help you better. I review your showed code and I find no bug on service block.

Comment: I have never created jsbin or jsfiddle, but I will try.  The fact that you find "no bug" on service block is basically my point.  This only happens when I add a "new" function, and it happens just about every time I add one, then it just starts working for no reason.  However, this time, it has NOT started working and I'm getting frustrated with it because I will have to create more functions and the problem is causing a real slow down in my project.  I will try to create the jsfiddle.  I don't know how it will work without the data which comes from my MVC Controller and repositories.

Comment: I created the jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/RaniRadcliff/afv4t8h2/  I'm not sure what else to do.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: I will to write an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your code working:

https://jsfiddle.net/afv4t8h2/1/

You need to put the script for service before the script of controller, and also, had a small error on your code:

```
<li ng-repeat="region in serviceRegions">{{region.}}</li>
```

it's an non ended angular expression... correct to {{ region }}